# How can I close/stop a FaunaDB stream?

Tags: faunadb

I am able to start a FaunaDB stream. The user enters a room name and the function *setupStream* is called

Once a stream is started, the clock is ticking and resources are being used. I would like to able to stop the stream when the user has been inactive some time (the *stopStream* function is called). Is there a *stop()* method on the stream? I have tried *close()*, but it seems not to work

**room_stream.js**

```
var stream
var query
let collection_name = 'rooms';
var document_reference;
var client;

export function connectToFauna() {
    connectToFauna = () => {}; // this means connectToFauna is only called once
    client = new window.faunadb.Client({
        secret: process.env.<SECRET>,
        domain: 'db.fauna.com',
    });
};

export function setupStream(room_name) {
    console.log({room_name})
    query = window.faunadb.query;
    document_reference = query.Ref(query.Collection(collection_name), room_name);
    startStream(client, document_reference);
}

export function stopStream() {
        stream.close()
        room_name = ''
        timeout = true
        console.log(stream)
    }
}

const startStream = (client, document) => {
    stream = client.stream.document(document)
    .on('snapshot', snapshot => {
        report('snapshot', snapshot);
    })
    .on('version', version => {
        report('version', version);
    })
    .on('error', error => {
        console.log('Error:', error);
        stream.close()
        if ( !timeout ) {
            console.log('restart')
            setTimeout(startStream, 1000);
        }
    })
    .start()
};

function report(action, event) {
    var data = ('action' in event) ? event["document"].data : event.data;
    room_data.set(data);
};
```

Comment: What did you see that made you think `close()` did not work?

Comment: Changes to the database still picked up by 'version' after the close() function called. Is it my logic?

Comment: It's hard to tell if it's your logic: your code defines `connectToFauna` but doesn't call it, for example. `close()` is expected to close a stream, so maybe you've encountered a bug. It might be better to post your question in the Fauna Forums, which is more conducive to a conversation that arrives at a solution.